# IOS UIActivityViewController redraw layout

Tags: ios, layout, uiviewcontroller, draw

I've added on my ios app a share button, it works fine, but there is a problem after send/close the dialog.
The problem is that all layout is moved up.

The code is:

```
        NSString *texttoshare = @"My App";

    NSURL *linkURL =  [NSURL URLWithString:article.fonte];

    NSArray *activityItems = @[texttoshare, linkURL];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];

    [activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {

    }];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Is possible to open/close di dialog without redraw the layout?

Comment: Add to your viewWillAppear this: self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

Comment: this commond doesn't work

Comment: the layout is under navigation bar

Comment: I did this proposal, because when navigationBar is translucent the view start behind it (the 0 , 0 point is on the top-left of the screen), but when is not translucent the view start above the navigation bat ( in the point 0 , 64 ). If you post the code in your view controller and a look of you general layout, we might be able to help you. But with the current information it´s impossible to reproduce you issue.

Comment: I've resolved. On iPad the code is different, I've added popovercontroller function. Thanks a lot